# Haskell - Rename duplicate values in a list of lists

Tags: haskell, duplicates, nested-lists

I have a list of lists of strings e.g;

```
[["h","e","l","l","o"], ["g","o","o","d"], ["w","o","o","r","l","d"]]
```

And I want to rename repeated values outside a sublist so that all the repetitions are set to new randomly generated values throughout a sublist that are not pre-existing in the list but the same inside the same sublist so that a possible result might be:

```
[["h","e","l","l","o"], ["g","t","t","d"], ["w","s","s","r","z","f"]]
```

I already have a function that can randomly generate a string of size one called `randomStr`:

```
randomStr :: String
randomStr = take 1 $ randomRs ('a','z') $ unsafePerformIO newStdGen
```

Comment: First of all, DO NOT USE `unsafePerformIO`, it won't work like this.  You have to make your `randomStr` function return `IO String` if you want that to work.

Comment: Since you're always returning a single character in your string, it'd make more sense just to do `randomLetter :: IO Char; randomLetter = getStdRandom (randomR ('a', 'z'))`, similarly to the example in the [documentation for `System.Random`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-1.0.1.1/docs/System-Random.html#v:getStdRandom).

Comment: Also, to clarify what you actually want to do here, every time you encounter a letter in a sublist, if it had already appeared in a previous sublist, you want to replace each occurrence in that sublist with the same random value.  So here since `"o"` appears in `["h","e","l","l","o"]`, both `"o"`s in `["g","o","o","d"]` get replaced with the same random letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming you want to do what I've outlined in my comment below, it's best to break this problem up into several smaller parts to tackle one at a time.  I would also recommend leveraging common modules in `base` and `containers`, since it will make the code much simpler and faster.  In particular, the modules `Data.Map` and `Data.Sequence` are very useful in this case.  `Data.Map` I would say is the most useful here, as it has some very useful functions that would otherwise be difficult to write by hand.  `Data.Sequence` is used for efficiency purposes at the end, as you'll see.

First, imports:

```
import           Data.List      (nub)
import           Data.Map       (Map)
import           Data.Sequence  (Seq, (|>), (<|))
import qualified Data.Map       as Map
import qualified Data.Sequence  as Seq
import           Data.Foldable (toList)
import           System.Random (randomRIO)
import           Control.Monad (forM, foldM)
import           Control.Applicative ((<$>))
```

`Data.Foldable.toList` is needed since `Data.Sequence` does not have a `toList` function, but `Foldable` provides one that will work.  On to the code.  We first want to be able to take a list of `String`s and find all the unique elements in it.  For this, we can use `nub`:

```
lettersIn :: [String] -> [String]
lettersIn = nub
```

I like providing my own names for functions like this, it can make the code more readable.

Now that we can get all the unique characters, we want to be able to assign each a random character:

```
makeRandomLetterMap :: [String] -> IO (Map String String)
makeRandomLetterMap letters
    = fmap Map.fromList
    $ forM (lettersIn letters) $ \l -> do
        newL <- randomRIO ('a', 'z')
        return (l, [newL])
```

Here we get a new random character and essentially zip it up with our list of letters, then we `fmap` (`<$>`) `Map.fromList` over that result.  Next, we need to be able to use this map to replace letters in a list.  If a letter isn't found in the Map, we just want the letter back.  Luckily, `Data.Map` has the `findWithDefault` function which is perfect for this situation:

```
replaceLetter :: Map String String -> String -> String
replaceLetter m letter = Map.findWithDefault letter letter m

replaceAllLetters :: Map String String -> [String] -> [String]
replaceAllLetters m letters = map (replaceLetter m) letters
```

Since we want to be able to update this map with new letters that have been encountered in each sublist, overwriting previously encountered letters as needed, we can use `Data.Map.union`.  Since `union` favors its first argument, we need to `flip` it:

```
updateLetterMap :: Map String String -> [String] -> IO (Map String String)
updateLetterMap m letters = flip Map.union m <$> makeRandomLetterMap letters
```

Now we have all the tools needed to tackle the problem at hand:

```
replaceDuplicatesRandomly :: [[String]] -> IO [[String]]
replaceDuplicatesRandomly [] = return []
```

For the base case, just return an empty list.

```
replaceDuplicatesRandomly (first:rest) = do
    m <- makeRandomLetterMap first
```

For a non-empty list, make the initial map off the first sublist

```
    (_, seqTail) <- foldM go (m, Seq.empty) rest
```

Fold over the rest, starting with an empty sequence and the first map, and extract the resulting sequence

```
    return $ toList $ first <| seqTail
```

Then convert the sequence to a list after prepending the first sublist (it doesn't get changed by this function).  The `go` function is pretty simple too:

```
    where
        go (m, acc) letters = do
            let newLetters = replaceAllLetters m letters
            newM <- updateLetterMap m letters
            return (newM, acc |> newLetters)
```

It takes the current map `m` and an accumulation of all the sublists processed so far `acc` along with the current sublist `letters`, replaces the letters in said sublist, builds a new map for the next iteration (`newM`), and then returns the new map along with the accumulation of everything processed, i.e. `acc |> newLetters`.  All together, the function is

```
replaceDuplicatesRandomly :: [[String]] -> IO [[String]]
replaceDuplicatesRandomly [] = return []
replaceDuplicatesRandomly (first:rest) = do
    m <- makeRandomLetterMap first
    (_, seqTail) <- foldM go (m, Seq.empty) rest
    return $ toList $ first <| seqTail
    where
        go (m, acc) letters = do
            let newLetters = replaceAllLetters m letters
            newM <- updateLetterMap m letters
            return (newM, acc |> newLetters)
```

Comment: That was a lot to take in as a beginner at Haskell but it was very well explained, and it's working. Thank you so much for your time! The syntax is quite tricky and I need to get used to it. Is there a link that you would recommend?

Comment: If you haven't read it already, [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters) is a great place to get started.  After that, you can read Real World Haskell, but it's starting to get fairly dated.  The best I can recommend after that is tutorials on FPComplete's website and Gabriel Gonzalez has a great set of posts on his website [Haskell for all](http://www.haskellforall.com/).

Comment: @SalmaFG Honestly, I could have made this code more idiomatic by bringing in the state monad to keep up with a `StdGen` and the current map, it would make the computations actually pure, all it would need is to be fed an initial generator.  This actually makes it easier to test since you can supply a fixed generator to make sure you keep getting the right output.  However, I decided to not bring in extra monads beyond IO into this right now.

Answer (score 1):

It's always better to keep impure and pure computations separated.

You cannot replace by letters, which are already in a list, so you need to get a string of fresh letters:

```
fresh :: [String] -> String
fresh xss = ['a'..'z'] \\ foldr union [] xss
```

This function replaces one letter with another in a string:

```
replaceOne :: Char -> Char -> String -> String
replaceOne y y' = map (\x -> if x == y then y' else x)
```

This function replaces one letter each time with a new letter for every string in a list of strings:

```
replaceOnes :: Char -> String -> [String] -> (String, [String])
replaceOnes y = mapAccumL (\(y':ys') xs ->
    if y `elem` xs
       then (ys', replaceOne y y' xs)
       else (y':ys', xs))
```

For example

```
replaceOnes 'o' "ijklmn" ["hello", "good", "world"]
```

returns

```
("lmn",["helli","gjjd","wkrld"])
```

A bit tricky one:

```
replaceMany :: String -> String -> [String] -> (String, [String])
replaceMany ys' ys xss = runState (foldM (\ys' y -> state $ replaceOnes y ys') ys' ys) xss
```

This function replaces each letter from `ys` each time with a new letter from `ys'` for every string in `xss`.

For example

```
replaceMany "mnpqstuvxyz" "lod" ["hello", "good", "world"]
```

returns

```
("vxyz",["hemmp","gqqt","wsrnu"])
```

i.e.

```
'l's in "hello" are replaced by the first   letter in "mnpqstuvxyz"
'l'  in "world" is  replaced by the second  letter in "mnpqstuvxyz"
'o'  in "hello" is  replaced by the third   letter in "mnpqstuvxyz"
'o's in "good"  are replaced by the fourth  letter in "mnpqstuvxyz"
...
'd'  in "world" is  replaced by the seventh letter in "mnpqstuvxyz"
```

This function goes through a list of strings and replaces all letters from the head by fresh letters, that `ys'` contains, for each string in the rest of the list.

```
replaceDuplicatesBy :: String -> [String] -> [String]
replaceDuplicatesBy ys'  []      = []
replaceDuplicatesBy ys' (ys:xss) = ys : uncurry replaceDuplicatesBy (replaceMany ys' ys xss)
```

I.e. it does what you want, but without any randomness — just picks fresh letters from a list.

All described functions are pure. Here is an impure one:

```
replaceDuplicates :: [String] -> IO [String]
replaceDuplicates xss = flip replaceDuplicatesBy xss <$> shuffle (fresh xss)
```

I.e. generate a random permutation of a string, that contains fresh letters, and pass it to `replaceDuplicatesBy`.

You can take the `shuffle` function from https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Random_shuffle

And the final test:

```
main = replicateM_ 3 $ replaceDuplicates ["hello", "good", "world"] >>= print
```

prints

```
["hello","gxxd","wcrzy"]
["hello","gyyd","wnrmf"]
["hello","gmmd","wvrtx"]
```

The whole code (without `shuffle`): http://lpaste.net/115763

Answer (score -2):

I think this is bound to raise more questions than it answers.

```
import Control.Monad.State
import Data.List
import System.Random

mapAccumLM _ s [] = return (s, [])
mapAccumLM f s (x:xs) = do
  (s', y) <- f s x
  (s'', ys) <- mapAccumLM f s' xs
  return (s'', y:ys)

pick excluded for w = do
  a <- pick' excluded
  putStrLn $ "replacement for " ++ show for ++ " in " ++ show w ++ " excluded: " ++ show excluded ++ " = " ++ show a
  return a

-- | XXX -- can loop indefinitely
pick' excluded = do
  a <- randomRIO ('a','z')
  if elem a excluded
    then pick' excluded
    else return a

transform w = do
  globallySeen <- get
  let go locallySeen ch =
        case lookup ch locallySeen of
          Nothing  -> if elem ch globallySeen
                        then do let excluded = globallySeen ++ (map snd locallySeen)
                                a <- lift $ pick excluded ch w
                                return ( (ch, a):locallySeen, a)
                        else return ( (ch,ch):locallySeen,       ch )
          Just ch' -> return (locallySeen, ch')
  (locallySeen, w') <- mapAccumLM go [] w
  let globallySeen' = w' ++ globallySeen
  put globallySeen'
  return w'

doit ws = runStateT (mapM transform ws) []

main = do
 ws' <- doit [ "hello", "good", "world" ]
 print ws'
```

Comment: I'll fess-up to the down-vote.  A blob of code with no discussion or even type signatures is indeed bound to raise questions and not answer them.

Comment: That's fine - everyone is entitled to their view.